# ASP.Net Core MVC DisplayFormat not removing the time element of a date

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am using ASP.Net Core MVC 5.0

I am trying to format a datetime? field so that it omits the time part and just displays the date.

I have the following

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? NextRenewalDueAt { get; set; }
```

But it still displays the time part - 01/02/2021 00:00:00

I display -

```
Registered on: @Model.Place.NextRenewalDueAt
```

How can I get rid of the time part?

Thanks

Comment: `ASP.Net Core MVC 5.0` - is that MVC 5.0 (pre-core), MVC Core (which never reached version 5), or MVC on .NET 5 (post-core)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Registered on: @Model.Place.NextRenewalDueAt
```

The formatting string is applied to the field value only when bind the value of the data-bound control (such as: Html Helper: `EditorFor()` and `DisplayFor()`, [Asp.net Core Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-5.0): Input). By using the above code, you just get the date from the Model, without bind to the data-bound control, so, it will show the original format (like this:  `6/3/2021 2:29:23 PM`).

To solve this issue, you could use the following methods:

1. Use Html.DisplayFor() method:

   ```
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NextRenewalDueAt)
   ```
2. Change the Date format in the View.

   Registered on: `@(Model.Place.NextRenewalDueAt.HasValue ? Model.Place.NextRenewalDueAt.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") : "")`
3. Using Input Tag helper:

   `<input asp-for="NextRenewalDueAt" class="form-control" type="text" readonly/>`

   [Note] Since, the Input Tag Helper sets the HTML type attribute based on the .NET type. To format the datetime data type, we should set the `type` attribute to `text`, otherwise, it will use the `type="datetime-local"`. More detail information, see [The Input Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-input-tag-helper).

Comment: Thanks, Zhi Lv changing the date format in the View worked!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to set `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`, because it will just be a display date. So you can try these options:

1. Html.DisplayFor

   Registered on: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NextRenewalDueAt)
2. Format on the view

   @{
   var tempDate = Model.Place.NextRenewalDueAt.HasValue ? Model.Place.NextRenewalDueAt.ToShortDateString() : "";
   }

   Registered on: @tempDate